# How to ReSign the .ipa file?

Tags: iphone

I already have an ipa file & want to ReSign . When ever i do so the size of generated ipa do not match the actual size . Can anyone help ?

I have tried using iReSign os x application & also using Terminal & the generated ipa doesn't install on iPhone .

Comment: @all i found a solution . While using iReSign just don't give any path on entitlement.plist field else fill everything & this works fine .